# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: php

I'm receiving this error ad I can't really find the solution myself so I was wondering if you could help me out.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in header.php on line 59
```

This is my header.php

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title><?php wp_title('|',1,'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>

    <style type="text/css">body>.container{background:#ffffff;border:1px solid #cacaca;}</style>
  </head>
  <body class="clearfix" id="body">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
     <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'horizon_logo' ) ) : ?>
            <div class="site-logo">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'horizon_logo' ) ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"></a>
            </div>

                <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
            </a>
    </div>

        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
        ?>
        </nav>
</div>

  <div class="container">
```

Any help is appreciated
The container tag is basicly line 59 so I don't see what could be wrong with it.

Comment: It says the error is on line 59 and you posted only 56. But first of all the if() statement isn't closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'horizon_logo' ) ) : ?>
```

You don't seem to close this conditional statement.

Comment: Wow, I indeed forgot <?php endif; ?> .. XD thank you.
Works now

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing tag for if statement

```
<?php endif; ?>
```